# Javascript - Getting a script's own souce code from within the script

Tags: javascript, reflection

So I have a problem where I need to get the entirety of a script's source code as a string (whether it's an inline script or a script that uses the src attribute) from within the script itself, but without knowing beforehand exactly what script it is. I can't just do an XHR for that reason. Several scripts on the page will listen for events, and when they handle them they will also run code that identifies the script's own source code. How should I do this?

```
function identifySelf() {
    // Some code here
    return mysource; // should return the source code of the script in which this function is defined
}
```

Comment: May be a possible XY question. What exactly do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify each script tag with an id. Then

```
var script=document.getElementById("my_id");
var content=script.innerHTML || "";
if(content==null || content==""){
    var src=script.src;
    // ajax in the script, I'm not going to write the code because I'm on mobile
    // I'm assuming you can write it yourself
}
```

EDIT: sorry, I didn't read your question fully. If you need to return the content right away, you will need to ajax in scripts' content on page load, and the return cached content. There is no way to just get the innerHTML like that.